# Adding extra elements conditionally with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using Bootstrap and want to create rows of content, with each row containing three columns, where each column's content would represent one object in ng-repeat.

It would look like this:

```
<div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Panel content
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Panel content
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Panel content
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Panel content
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Panel content
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Panel content
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

What is the best way to go about this? I essentially need to add something along the lines of

```
</div>
<div class="row">
```

In between every three objects in the ng-repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to display 3 panel in each row.

If you'r using `col-md-4` on your panels then bootstrap will place 3 panels in each row (as long as the screen size is at least MD size) - So, adding `row` to every three rows is not only unnecessary it might even prevent certain functionalists (like displaying only 2 for SM devices).

Regarding angular, you can access the index inside the loop using `$index`.

Answer (score 0):

I did a research and it seems you can't wrap the elements of `ng-repeat`.

Your best bet is to use two-dimensional array. Keep a `rows` array, where each `item` represents an `array of objects`. So you have to write two nested `ng-repeat`s, like this:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="row in rows">
    <div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="object in row">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is [the working example](http://jsfiddle.net/F3K5f/) with your HTML structure, but with a random data.

Also, this approach will allow you to change the number of objects in each row dynamically in code.